# azure web app for containers with nexus registry

Tags: azure, docker, web-applications, containers, nexus

We are trying to create web app for Containers in azure and nexus is our repo. When we configure nexus repo details in contianer settings in Azure web app for containers we are getting below error.

```
ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://nexus.chubbdigital.com:8086/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client"}
```

When i searched in Google, noticed that there are some insecure registries need to be entered in docker deamon config file. But how can we add insecure entries in web app for containers?

Comment: Can you provide the registry setting that you do?